# Critical Error - Start Menu Not Working for single AAD user across all devices

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, azure-activedirectory, intune

One of my Azure Active Directory users is getting a message "Critical Error - Start Menu Not Working" whenever she clicks on the start menu. There are several resources online for how to address this when it happens to a standard user profile but this is happening immediately on any device she logs in on. Any other user logging in to the same devices does not have the problem.
None of the suggestions I have found so far work: reinstalling from powershell, safe boot or clean boot.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What sort of things is the domain applying for this user? Policies?

Comment: Yeah, Configuration Profiles. Mainly locking down the settings interface. The same profile is applied to 80% of our users, but only this user is having this issue.

Comment: I'd create her a new account and copy the data over, especially as this is a significant impact on a user. Yes, it would be nice to find and solve the root problem, but that may take a while, and while I'm not saying it was gremlins...